# Sygic URL scheme - App does not open

Tags: ios, url-scheme, openurl, sygic

I am trying to integrate the most popular navigation apps into my app, and all of those I chose work, except for Sygic.

Following [this guide](http://dev.sygic.com/documentation/custom-url-schema/), I wrote the code:

```
NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.sygic.aura://coordinate|%f|%f|drive",
                                           self.coordinate.longitude,
                                           self.coordinate.latitude];
      
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
```

But when the code is run, Sygic doesn't open, nothing happens.

Checking `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"com.sygic.aura://"]]` returns `YES` when the app is installed and `NO` when it's not (as it should).

I tested using "Sygic Brasil" and "Sygic (All Regions)", version 13, but neither will open.
I also tried percent-escaping the URL string, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Try to add `http://` before `com.sygic.aura` and check it.

Comment: Tried `http://com.sygic.aura/coordinate|%f|%f|drive`, still nothing :/

Comment: Have you added URL types in `info.plist` file?

Comment: Why should I? It's not my app that will handle this URL. Moreover, I didn't have to add for the other navigation apps. Still, I should give it a try. Update: yes, it did not work :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you try following code,

```
NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.sygic.aura://coordinate|%f|%f|drive",
                                       self.coordinate.longitude,
                                       self.coordinate.latitude];

NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ];

if(newURL)
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:newURL];
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Something wrong with lat or long or both");
}
```

Comment: Add `http://` here also. Even I am able to open url in safari, but its unable to open page. For me your url is   http://com.sygic.aura://coordinate%7C78.345000%7C17.989000%7Cdrive

Comment: Actually, your first answer was right. I was using stringBy **Replacing** instead of **Adding**. Of course that wouldn't escape correctly. And the URL used has to be the one I used in first place (without `http://`).

Comment: please try simple http url like "http://www.google.com" if that does not work check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677087/uiapplication-sharedapplicationopenurl-can-not-launch-safari